# does the code violate the Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: design-patterns, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I'm having a bit of a hard time trying to understand the Liskov Substitution Principle and was wondering if the following code violates the Liskov Substitution Principle?

```
public class Task {

     String status = "Ready"; // One of "Ready", "Started", and "Closed"

     public void setStatus(String newStatus) {
          status = newStatus;
     }
     public void cancel() {
          status = "Closed";
     }
}
public class ProjectTask extends Task {

     @Override
     public void cancel() {
          if (status.equals("Started")) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Cannot cancel a started project task.");
          }

          super.cancel();
     }
}
```

I think it does since the subclass doesn't behave like the base class when it is substituted and also because it throws a RunTimeException?

I'm not entirely sure and was wondering if my assumption was correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subclass doesn't have to behave the same way as the base class.  It has to implement the base class' contract.

Unfortunately, you didn't document the base class' contract, so I can't say whether or not it is correct.   If it's like this:

```
public class Task {
    ...

    /**
     * Attempt to cancel the task.
     *
     * @throws RuntimeException if the task is not in a cancellable state
     */
    public void cancel() {
        status = "Closed";
    }
}
```

... then it's just fine.

The contract means that anybody who calls `Task.cancel` needs to anticipate an exception.

You see, LSP isn't just about what the base class does, or what the subclass does.  It's about the code that uses these things.

LSP says that when a method or constructor is declared to take `Task` as an argument, then the declaration promises that it works not just with direct `Task` implementations, but all valid subclass implementations, because a `ProjectTask` IS a `Task`.

Your job as an engineer is to make sure those promises are kept.

Comment: so if all tasks are supposed to be cancellable at any state then would the projecttask violate the LSP?

Comment: Yes indeed. Or if `Task.cancel` is supposed to fail without an exception for tasks that can't be cancelled